# Sort a list of dicts by dict values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'title':'New York Times', 'title_url':'New_York_Times','id':4},
 {'title':'USA Today','title_url':'USA_Today','id':6},
 {'title':'Apple News','title_url':'Apple_News','id':2}]
```

I'd like to sort it by the title, so elements with A go before Z:

```
[{'title':'Apple News','title_url':'Apple_News','id':2},
 {'title':'New York Times', 'title_url':'New_York_Times','id':4},
 {'title':'USA Today','title_url':'USA_Today','id':6}]
```

What's the best way to do this?
Also, is there a way to ensure the order of each dictionary key stays constant, e.g., always title, title_url, then id?

Comment: May I ask why you need a sorted dict? Normally you are accessing a dict via keys anyway, so the order does not matter.

Comment: Er, it's a list of dicts Felix.

Comment: @Amber: Yeah I see... but anyway his second question is targeting at this ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python how do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 20):

```
l.sort(key=lambda x:x['title'])
```

To sort with multiple keys, assuming all in ascending order:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x:(x['title'], x['title_url'], x['id']))
```

Comment: +1, using `key` and pulling the proper attribute is more correct/cleaner than just using a `lambda` as the sort function

Comment: Yeah, I just remembered that as well - Python 2.4+ has them, so they're probably available.

Answer (score 19):

The hypoallergenic alternative for those who sneeze when approached by lambdas:

```
import operator
L.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('title','title_url','id'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `.sort(fn)` on the list, where `fn` is a function which compares the title values and returns the result of the comparison.

```
mylist.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(x['title'], y['title']))
```

In later versions of Python, though (2.4+), it's much better to just use a sort key:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x:x['title'])
```

Also, dictionaries are guaranteed to keep their order, were you to iterate through keys/values, as long as there are no more additions/removals. If you add or remove items, though, all bets are off, there's no guarantee for that.

Answer (score -1):

```
originalList.sort(lambda d1, d2: cmp(d1['title'], d2['title']))
```

Though this only sorts on title and order after that is undefined.  Doing multiple levels would be painful this way.

Comment: `cmp` is deprecated with good reason as `key` is much better. Sorting on multiple levels is easy - just use tuples see Kenny's answer

Comment: The order after that is defined as the order in which they originally occurred. (Python sorts are stable.)