# How to sort a list by dict values in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

Let's say I have a list:

```
b = [ {'id':'e1'},{'id':'e100'},{'id':'e3'},{'id':'e2'}  ]
```

I want to sort it by id numbers to look like that:

```
b = [{'id': 'e1'}, {'id': 'e2'}, {'id': 'e3'}, {'id': 'e100'}]
```

Comment: No, or you're not sure? Could you become sure, *then* try to write the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: True duplicate: [Sort a list of dicts by dict values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878084/sort-a-list-of-dicts-by-dict-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sorted`. The following solution works, provided the value of 'id' starts with a single character followed by numbers.

```
sorted(b, key=lambda x: int(x['id'][1:]))
```

Comment: @Tomas - Glad I could help.